# Eliminar y renombrar columnas de un DataTable en C#

Tags: c#, datatables, foreach, dataset

Tengo el siguiente metodo:

```
public DataSet GetReportsTransactions(FilterHome filterHome, int TypeChart)
    {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        string IdStore = "";
        IdStore = "Sp_Report_Transactions_Dinamic";
        var idUser = filterHome.IdUser;
        var idgroup = filterHome.FilterGroups.IdGroup;
        var idchain = filterHome.FilterGroups.IdCadena;
        var idmerchant = filterHome.FilterGroups.IdComercio;
        var filterState = filterHome.FilterState;
        var filterDinamic = filterHome.FilterDinamic;
        var idGroupMerchant = filterHome.IdGroupMerchant;
        var filterReport = filterHome.FilterReports;
        var monto = filterReport.Amount;
        var dateStart = filterReport.InitialDateReport;
        var dateEnd = filterReport.FinalDateReport;
        var tipoReporte = filterReport.TypeReports;
        var aplication = filterReport.IdApp;
        var tipoTransaccion = filterReport.TypeTransaction;
        using (var cnn = new SqlConnection(_affiliate_portal))
        {
            SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand(IdStore, cnn);

            DynamicParameters parameters = new DynamicParameters();

            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_User", idUser);
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_TypeChar", TypeChart);
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_Group", idgroup);
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_Chain", idchain);
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_Merchant", idmerchant);
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_State", filterState.IdState);
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_Municipality", filterState.IdMunicipale);
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_GroupMerchant", idGroupMerchant);
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_App", aplication );
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", monto);
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TypeTransactions", tipoTransaccion);
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TypeReports", tipoReporte);               
            if (dateStart == null)
                sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_Start", DBNull.Value);
            else
                sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_Start", dateStart);
            if (dateEnd == null)
                sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_End", DBNull.Value);
            else
                sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_End", dateEnd);

            cnn.Open();

            sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            sqlComm.CommandTimeout = cnn.ConnectionTimeout;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = sqlComm;
            da.Fill(ds);
            foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(column.ColumnName);
                    if (column.ColumnName == "ID")
                    {
                        var ok = column.ColumnName;
                        table.Columns.Remove(ok);
                    }
                    //Console.WriteLine(column.ColumnName);
                    if (column.ColumnName == "Card")
                    {
                        var ok = column.ColumnName;
                        table.Columns["Card"].ColumnName = "Tarjeta";
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        return ds;
    }
```

El punto es que al elminar la columna recibo un error del tipo: **Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute**.

Según lo que investigué es porque elimino un elemento de la tabla que recorro, alguna manera de resolverlo?

Deseo eliminar coumnas y renombrar dependiendo el caso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de esta línea:

```
da.Fill(ds);
```

Obtenga la tabla en una variable separada:

```
DataTable table1 = ds.Tables[0]; // suponiendo que solo devuelva 1 tabla.
```

Remueva la columna fuera del `foreach`, usando el método `.Remove`.

Ejemplo:

```
table1.Columns.Remove("ID");
```

o

```
ds.Tables[0].Columns.Remove("ID"); // Suponiendo que "ds" contiene solo 1 tabla.
```

Answer (score 1):

Un bloque foreach, realiza una iteración por todos los objetos que componen una colección, en tu ejemplo el primer bloque foreach itera por todos los objetos "DataTable"  en la colección del objeto "ds.Tables", el segundo bloque foreach itera por todos los objetos "DataColumn"  en la colección del objeto "table.Columns". 
El error en tu código radica en que dentro de un bloque foreach, la colección del objeto que se está recorriendo no se puede modificar, pues genera un error y eso es algo de una lógica elemental; la modificación de la colección que estas recorriendo ocurre cuando intentas eliminar una columna del objeto "table.Columns" con el método "table.Columns.Remove(ok)", debes razonar que si tu objeto "table.Columns" tenia 10 columnas por ejemplo, después de eliminar una tendría 9, eso el bloque foreach, no lo soporta.
Pero tu ejemplo tiene una solución muy elegante, perfectamente compatible con tu ejemplo y consiste en eliminar las columnas dentro del primer bloque foreach, para lo cual basta con hacer referencia directamente al objeto "ds.Tables.Columns" en ese bloque, la linea de código para eliminar la columnas "ID" quedaría de esta forma "ds.Tables.Columns.Remove("ID")", solo que si la columna ID no existe en la tabla, se generaría un error en tiempo de ejecución, para evitar ese error se puede insertar la sentencia if de la siguiente forma: "if(table.Columns.Contains("ID"))"
Con esta solución el código de tu primer bloque foreach quedaría asi:

```
  foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
   {
      if(table.Columns.Contains("ID"))
          table.Columns.Remove("ID");
      if (table.Columns.Contains("Card"))
          table.Columns.Remove("Card");
   }
```

El segundo bloque foreach no haria falta, solo serviría para sobrecargar tu código y consumir tiempo de CPU durante su ejecución, haciendo más lento tu software, observar que cuando se elimina una columna se esta modificando el objeto Columns correspondiente al objeto DataTable actual, pero la colección "ds.Tables" que es el objeto de iteración no se modifica.

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta, lo había solucionado, pero tu idea es correcta y puede ayudar a alguien mas. Saludos.

Comment: @Abraham, Gracias por tu puntuación y tu comentario.